# Xamarin Android Api 29 Q10 can not reconnect to Wifi

Tags: android, api, xamarin, wifi

My app connects to a hotspot and then remove it. My issue is that the phone does not reconnect after to the previous WiFi network with the API 29. Any idea how to use new API?

This code used to work but is now obsolete:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = 
   (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
var wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration{Ssid = $"\"{hotspotName}\""};
var network = wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Ssid == wifiConfig.Ssid);
wifiManager.Disconnect();
wifiManager.RemoveNetwork(networkId);                   
wifiManager.Reconnect();
```

new code that fails to reconnect to available WiFi:

```
WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder wifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder = new 
    WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();
wifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.SetSsid(ssid);
WifiNetworkSuggestion wifiNetworkSuggestion = 
    wifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder.Build();
IList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> wifiNetworkSuggestions = new 
     List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> { wifiNetworkSuggestion };
 NetworkStatus networkStatus = 
     WifiManager.RemoveNetworkSuggestions(wifiNetworkSuggestions);
```

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Android do you have? I am wondering because I have tried using the WifiNetworkSuggestion approach, and I do not see the WifiNetworkSuggestion or WifiNetworkSpecifier classes available or documented at all within the current version 10.0.6.2.

Comment: I am using the latest at the time your posted, not sure about the version number

Answer (score 1):

The `Reconnect` and `RemoveNetwork` methods was deprecated in API level 29/Q and always return false on that API level.

You should now use `WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()` on 29/Q to have an application-level scope wifi connection and since it is app scoped, you do not have to remove it and reconnect to the user's previous wifi network as the OS will now do it for you.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder

Comment: Yes this is precisely the issue. With the new methods, I have been able to remove the WiFi but unable to get another WiFi configured with internet to reconnect.